# Getting the body of a Reddit submission?

Tags: reddit, praw

I am trying to search for some data by scraping Reddit. I want to get the self-text of the posts in the subreddit, not the title/url. How can I do this? Here's my code that I am using to get the titles, but how can I get the text written in the posts with this title?

```py
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id=cid,
                     client_secret=secret, password=pass_word,
                     user_agent='mmm', username=user_name)

subreddit = reddit.subreddit('python')
subreddit_hot=subreddit.hot(limit=5)
for submission in subreddit_hot:
    if not submission.stickied:
        print(submission.title)
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace `print(submission.title)` with `print(submission.selftext)`.

To see other attributes of a `Submission` object, take a look at [the PRAW docs](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/submission.html#praw.models.Submission), which has a table of common attributes for the model. PRAW's documentation also features [a guide for discovering attributes on any model](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/quick_start.html#determine-available-attributes-of-an-object).